# How to use sed to identify a string in brackets?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to find the string in that is placed with in the brackets. How do I use sed to pull the string?

```
# cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]
```

I'm not getting the exact result

```
# cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler | sed 's/\[*\]//'
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq
```

I'm expecting an output

```
cfq
```

Comment: Does it have to be sed? `grep` seems better for this case.

Comment: I'm open to all options. Can grep give me the the string `cfq` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easier with `grep`, if it happens to be changing the position in which the text in between brackets is located:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=\[)[^]]*' file
cfq
```

This is look-behind: whenever you find a string `[`, start fetching all the characters up to a `]`.

See another example:

```
$ cat a
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]
hello this [is something] we want to [enclose] yeah

$ grep -Po '(?<=\[)[^]]*' a
cfq
is something
enclose
```

---

You can also use `awk` for this, in case it is always in the same position:

```
$ awk -F[][] '{print $2}' file
cfq
```

It is setting the field separators as `[` and `]`. And from that, prints the second one.

And with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/[^[]*\[\([^]]*\).*/\1/g' file
cfq
```

It is a bit messy, but basically it is looking from the block of text in between `[]` and prints it back.

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution-

```
cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1
```

so the exact solution is

```
# cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is awk:

```
s='noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]'
awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
cfq
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way by gnu grep :

```
grep -Po "\[\K[^]]*" file
```

with pure shell:

```
while read line; do   [[ "$line" =~ \[([^]]*)\] ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
echo 'noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]' | awk '{gsub(/.*\[|\].*/,x)}8'
cfq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/\[([^\]]*)\]/)'
```

Tested [here](http://ideone.com/2PflIo)